# Rspec, fake class AR attribute

Tags: ruby, activerecord

Hello i am trying to test method that in one place calls activerecord attribute, but however in test i created fake class to test it out and do not have a table for that test class, so how i could give that class a fake table or smthng?

tried to define load schema, but that didn't work:

```
class TestClassStatus < FrozenRecord::Base
end

class TestClass < ApplicationRecord
  def self.load_schema!
    @columns_hash={"test_class_status_id" => {@name=>'test_class_status_id', @table_name=>'TestClassStatus', @sql_type_metadata=>{ @sql_type=>'character varying', @type=>:string, @limit=>nil, @precision=>nil, @scale=>nil }, @null=>false, @default=>'', @default_function=>nil, @collation=>nil, @comment=>nil, @max_identifier_length=>63}}
  end

  has_status
end
```

here i have `TestClassStatus` where statuses from yml file are loaded by frozen record, and `TestClass` is a class where i use the method i want to test `has_status`. And that method is trying to find `test_class_status_id` in `TestClass`. But unfortunately i dont have a table for that fake `TestClass`. So any advice how to make a fake table for that TestClass to run this spec? :)
Thank you in advance!

Here is a part where it breakes

```
name = status_name ? status_name.to_s : "#{self.to_s}Status"
klass = name.camelize.constantize

include Module.new {
  class_eval %Q{
    def #{association_name}
      #{klass}.find(self[:#{name.underscore}])
    end
  }
}
```

It  brakes in line where it tries to find that attribute. klass in my case will be `TestClassStatus` and name will be `test_class_status` so in that line it tries to recieve `test_class_status` attribute in `TestClass`, but unfortunately as you can see my `TestClass` does not have a table. So i need somehow to fake the table, because this method hits activerecord :)

There is a way to test it using real class, but I don't want to be attached to a real class in testing in case someday i would need to remove that class.

Comment: can you show us the test case and the error?

Comment: Added more context :)

Comment: why do you "need a table"? What is the actual test?

Comment: beacuse as you can see method in included module hits active record, and i dont have that activerecord attribute in my fake class